# how to install Crawler-Detect given the instructions?

Tags: php, installation

Sorry in advance if it the questions seems too basic. But I want to know how to install "Crawler-Detect" in my xampp and online server?

The instructions are given in the git link at: https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect

I just don't know how to install them. no one else seem to be having problem with this.

So far I have tried to download the package, place it where my project is, required the class like any regular class in php and run it. this error occured:

Fatal error: Class 'CrawlerDetect' not found in H:\xampp\htdocs\viralagain\theme\crawl.php on line 5

Then installed the composer package and run the command:
  composer require jaybizzle/crawler-detect 1.*

This Error occured:

Fatal error: Class 'Jaybizzle\CrawlerDetect\CrawlerDetect' not found in H:\xampp\htdocs\viralagain\theme\crawl.php on line 5

Then in my composer.js (In The project directory) I added the 
"jaybizzle/crawler-detect" :"1.*"

Same error.

Crawl.php:

```
<?php

require "Jaybizzle/src/CrawlerDetect.php";
use Jaybizzle\CrawlerDetect\CrawlerDetect;

$CrawlerDetect = new CrawlerDetect;

// Check the user agent of the current 'visitor'
if($CrawlerDetect->isCrawler()) {
    // true if crawler user agent detected
    echo "</br> [BOT DETECTED]";
}else{
    echo "not a bot";
}

echo $botname = $CrawlerDetect->getMatches();
?>
```

Comment: What can we tell you that isn't already in the instructions?

Comment: I have installed the composer and run the given command.... but this error keeps coming:

Fatal error: Class 'CrawlerDetect' not found in H:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\theme\crawl.php on line 5

Also on servers where should I run the given command? it doesnt provide any commandline interface.

Comment: I have also included the command in composer.js but same error... may be just run me through the installing procedure, may be I am missing something.......

Comment: Please update your question: include there the steps you have done (in the order you have done them) and the error you get (and when exactly does it rise).

Comment: OK. I will do it..

Comment: Can you post your `crawl.php` file?

Comment: I was trying to use it with simple php... not any framework like Laravel.
I removed all the lines with "use" and put "required" in their places and it kind of worked...

Comment: If you show me your code, i'll try and help you make it better than 'kinda working'....im the author of Crawler Detect by the way :)

Comment: [Question edited]   Wow...didn't expect you to be here. 1st) , great work with this, really amazing. 2nd) I had to require before "use" statements and then remove the code where it gave "undefined variable" errors. Thnx again

Comment: @MarkBeech Kindly let me know if you think its the wrong way to use it....

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the CrawlerDetect's source and test it.

download it from here:
http://www.parsebazar.com/@files/CrawlerDetect.zip

sample:

```
require "CrawlerDetect.php";

$CrawlerDetect = new CrawlerDetect;

// Check the user agent of the current 'visitor'
if($CrawlerDetect->isCrawler()) {
    echo 'robot'; // true if crawler user agent detected
} else {
    echo 'visitor';
}
```